Concurrent triggers for denormalised table and transaction isolation
I have two main tables:
CREATE TABLE profiles(id int PRIMARY KEY, active bool);
CREATE TABLE memberships(scope VARCHAR(10), profile int);

And I have a denormalised table that combines data from the above two tables:
CREATE TABLE denormalised(scope VARCHAR(10), profile int, active bool);

The idea is this:

If a new profile is inserted, find the associated membership and insert into denormalised.
If a new membership is inserted, find the associated profile and insert into denormalised.

To do that I have two triggers:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION on_membership_insert()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO denormalised (scope, profile, active)
    SELECT NEW.scope, NEW.profile, p.active
    FROM profiles p
    WHERE p.id = NEW.profile
    FOR UPDATE
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_membership_insert
    AFTER INSERT ON memberships
    FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION on_membership_insert();


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION on_profile_insert()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO denormalised (scope, profile, active)
    SELECT m.scope, NEW.id, NEW.active
    FROM memberships m
    WHERE m.profile = NEW.id
    FOR UPDATE
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_profile_insert
    AFTER INSERT ON profiles
    FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION on_profile_insert();

The issue:
Concurrent insertions in both profiles and memberships result in nothing being inserted into denormalised.
Take these two transactions for example:
Tx1
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO profiles(id, active) VALUES (8, true);
-- wait, do not commit yet

Tx2
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO memberships(scope, profile) VALUES ('ub2', 8);
COMMIT;
-- now commit Tx1

I understand why the issue happens: the transactions cannot see each other's work and the FOR UPDATE does not force a re-calculation of rows for rows that have not been inserted yet (no EvalPlanQual).
My question:
What is the best way to correctly manage concurrent insertions in profiles and memberships?
One solution I found is to set the isolation level in both transactions to SERIALIZABLE. Is there a better way?

Prevent concurrent inserts by establishing a foreign key constraint between profiles and memberships. That will not only solve the problem, but prevent inconsistencies.

@LaurenzAlbe It's not an option unfortunately, for my business logic, I need to be able to insert a row in either table, even if the corresponding row does not exist.

You should fix your business logic. Otherwise, you end up using SERIALIZABLE or heavy locking, both of which impact your performance.

@LaurenzAlbe the business logic here is actually correct. My database sources profiles and memberships from different sources and there is no guarantee one will arrive before the other. Does that mean SERIALIZABLE is my best option here? If so, I assume the FOR UPDATE in the trigger doesn't do anything and can be removed, correct?

Yes, the FOR UPDATE has no positive effect, and SERIALIZABLE is probably your best option. I am not saying that your business logic doesn't work, I thought you might want to get good performance.
